# How can I draw a random sample from a dataset, proportionate to size, based on different proportions for each value of a factor variable, in R

Tags: r, random, tidyverse, sample

I want to draw a random sample from my dataset, using different proportions for each value of a factor variable, as well as using weights stored in some other column. `dplyr` solution in pipes will be preferred as it can be inserted easily in long code.

Let's take the example of `iris` dataset.  `Species` column is divided into three values 50 rows each.  Let's also assume the sample weights are stored in column `Sepal.Length`.  If I have to sample equal proportions (or equal rows) per species, the problem is easy to solve

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.1, weight_by = Sepal.Length)

# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
 1          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa    
 2          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa    
 3          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 setosa    
 4          5           3.5          1.6         0.6 setosa    
 5          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2 setosa    
 6          6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
 7          6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor
 8          5           2            3.5         1   versicolor
 9          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
10          5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor
11          7.2         3.2          6           1.8 virginica 
12          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8 virginica 
13          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1 virginica 
14          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
15          7.2         3            5.8         1.6 virginica
```

But I got stuck when I have to choose/sample different proportions for each species, say 10%, 20%, 25% respectively.

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice_sample(prop = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25), weight_by = Sepal.Length)

#Error: `prop` must be a single number
```

OR

```
iris %>% group_split(Species) %>% map_df(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25), ~ slice_sample(prop = ., weight_by = Sepal.Length))
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right:

```
iris %>% 
  group_split(Species) %>% 
  map2(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25), ~ slice_sample(.x, prop = .y))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
1          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
2          4.8         3            1.4         0.1 setosa 
3          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
4          5           3.5          1.6         0.6 setosa 
5          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2 setosa 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
 1          6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor
 2          5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
 3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
 4          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
 5          6.1         3            4.6         1.4 versicolor
 6          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
 7          6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
 8          5.1         2.5          3           1.1 versicolor
 9          5.7         3            4.2         1.2 versicolor
10          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor

[[3]]
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>    
 1          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3 virginica
 2          7.2         3.2          6           1.8 virginica
 3          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica
 4          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8 virginica
 5          7.6         3            6.6         2.1 virginica
 6          5.7         2.5          5           2   virginica
 7          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
 8          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4 virginica
 9          7.7         2.8          6.7         2   virginica
10          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
11          6           3            4.8         1.8 virginica
12          5.6         2.8          4.9         2   virginica
```

Just change `map2` to `map2_df` if you want a data frame returned:

```
iris %>% 
  group_split(Species) %>% 
  map2_df(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25), ~ slice_sample(.x, prop = .y))

# A tibble: 27 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
 1          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 setosa    
 2          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2 setosa    
 3          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa    
 4          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1 setosa    
 5          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa    
 6          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
 7          6.6         3            4.4         1.4 versicolor
 8          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
 9          5.8         2.7          4.1         1   versicolor
10          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# ... with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Yes, something like this, Can I use weight_by in this?

Comment: I suppose you can add `weight_by = Species` as an argument, I'm just not sure what purpose that serves (this is the part of your question I had trouble understanding).

Comment: Yes, Thanks for help.  I was using map_df! By the way what's the difference in map2_df and map_df?

Comment: Actually, `weight_by = Sepal.Length` works fine for me.  Weights by species indeed is meaningless.  In my datafram I have to carry sampling by probability proportionate to size without replacement, where actual weights are stored in some amount column.  To replicate it on `iris` I asked for weight-by on first numeric column only.

Comment: `map2()` is when you want to iterate through 2 sets of elements to go into a function's arguments instead of just 1. e.g. `map2(0:5, 1:6, function(x, y) rnorm(5, mean = x, sd = y))` will do `rnorm(5, 0, 1)`, then `rnorm(5, 1, 2)`, etc. up to `rnorm(5, 5, 6)`.

Comment: In my earlier comment, I meant to say `weight_by = Sepal.Length` instead of `weight_by = Species`. Either way, I don't think this is relevant to your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution using `purrr`.

First we specify our proportions for each `Species`.

```
props <- c(setosa=0.1, versicolor=0.2, virginica=0.5)
```

Then we iterate over each name-value pair in `props` using `imap`. For each pair in `props`, we filter the rows of data frame to only contain that species, and then sample the corresponding percentage that was specified using `slice_sample`.

```
imap_dfr(props,
         ~filter(iris, Species==.y) %>%
           slice_sample(prop=.x))
```

Using `imap_dfr` then puts together the three data frames (one for each species) into a single data frame.

Here's the result:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa
2           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa
3           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa
4           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
5           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
6           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor
7           5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
8           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 versicolor
9           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
10          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
11          5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
12          6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor
13          5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
14          5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor
15          5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
16          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica
17          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica
18          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
19          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica
20          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica
21          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica
22          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica
23          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8  virginica
24          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica
25          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica
26          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
27          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
28          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica
29          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica
30          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
31          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica
32          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
33          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica
34          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica
35          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica
36          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
37          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
38          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica
39          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
40          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the information of proportion in the dataframe itself and sample rows from it.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  distinct(Species) %>%
  mutate(prop = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25)) %>%
  inner_join(iris, by = 'Species') %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  sample_n(first(prop)*n()) -> result

result %>% count(Species)

#  Species        n
#  <fct>      <int>
#1 setosa         5
#2 versicolor    10
#3 virginica     12
```

I expected `slice_sample(prop = first(prop))` to work but it doesn't hence, I used `sample_n`.

Comment: Very good approach, as always Ronak.  Thanks.  Just to know can I set the seed within the pipe syntax or Do I have to set it at the beginning itself?

Comment: Setting it in the beginning itself should give you same samples.